# Double colored oval

Tags: java, swing, applet

I am a bit new in java and i have this stuff for homework. I have to make something like this

[image]

The thing is that i have no idea how to make the circle double colored with yellow and black stuff. Also after that with use of Threads i have to make it rotate counter clock wise. Here is my code for the circle, i know how to create it, just don't know how to multi color it >.< .

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JApplet;

public class Lab4a extends JApplet implements Runnable {
public void init() {
    Thread t = new Thread(this);
    t.start();
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
    int w = getWidth();
    int h = getHeight();

    g.drawOval(25, 35, 200, 200);
    g.drawOval(45, 55, 160, 160);
}
```

}

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: I know that they are not used anywhere, the teacher told us too but she said that we learn how to make GUI's in java with awt and swing.

Comment: You don't need to learn how to use the AWT components (that code doesn't use any).  And I was serious about letting her know about that article.  She is making the learning needlessly difficult.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at `drawArc` instead of `drawOval`. With this, you can paint arcs -- parts of ovals. You can specify the start and end angle of the arc, which can then also be used for drawing it in different states when it needs to rotate.

Comment: Thanks, i did draw it! :), now i need a bit help how to make it move counter clock wise with using threads :)

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15993204/using-threads-on-animations-in-java. Basic idea: use a thread that repeatedly calls repaint(), and have some logic that calculates how much your arcs should be rotated whenever they repaint.